# Laravel shared hosting, index.php not pointing to root but staying at public_htmls

Tags: php, laravel, shared-hosting

I have been working on deploying my Laravel app on a shared hosting using cpanel. However, I an getting this error:

```
[08-Sep-2018 07:38:43 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/daankraa/public_html/../../supersax/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/share/pear') in /home/daankraa/public_html/index.php on line 24
```

From what I can see here is that it doesn't want to switch to the root directory, but keeps looking for:

```
/home/daankraa/public_html/../../supersax/vendor/autoload.php in public_html.
```

I have tried the dots to move up a directory, but it doesn't want to. How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Daan

Comment: Did you move the index.php from the public folder into the root? Is that why index.php is in public_html?

Comment: Is `/home/daankraa/public_html/` the path to the laravel project?

Comment: If so then the path should be something like: `/home/daankraa/vendor/autoload.php`

Answer (score 1):

1) Copy
.htaccess from public folder to root

2)
rename server.php to index.php

server.php file would be in root

Simple :)

Comment: I dont have any server.php in my root.

Comment: check your application root folder

Comment: If server.php is not there then create index.php in root i am pasting index.php file code

Comment: check new answer if you don't have server.php

Comment: add index.php in your application root folder

Answer (score 1):

Move you all content from public to root directory and index.php file of public folder modified according like:

```
    require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

    $app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

index.php

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

$uri = urldecode(
    parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
);

// This file allows us to emulate Apache's "mod_rewrite" functionality from the
// built-in PHP web server. This provides a convenient way to test a Laravel
// application without having installed a "real" web server software here.
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri)) {
    return false;
}

require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple method that worked for for me:

1. create a .htaccess file in the public_html folder (the file is same level with .env file)
2. copy and paste the following code in the .htaccess file

   ```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
          Options -MultiViews -Indexes
      </IfModule>
    RewriteEngine on
    # serve existing files in the /public folder as if they were in /
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}public%{REQUEST_URI} -f
    RewriteRule (.+) /public/$1 [L]
    # route everything else to /public/index.php
    RewriteRule ^ /public/index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
   ```
3. Save the file. That's All you can now visit your site [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

Note: for some reason if it does not work the your document root might be different the you will have to use the full path to the public folder you will replace: {DOCUMENT_ROOT} with the full path /var/www/example.com/web, you can get the full path by creating a file in the public folder of laravel called get_doc_root.php and inside of that file paste the code

```
<?php
echo getcwd();
```

the you can see your path by going to [www.example.com/public/get_doc_root.php](http://www.example.com/public/get_doc_root.php)  after getting the path just copy it  and replace {DOCUMENT_ROOT} in your .htaccess created.